# Check the user Voice Channel status in Java

Tags: discord, discord-jda

In JavaScript, checking if the user's voice channel status would be:

(if the user is in a voice channel or not)

```
let voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

if (vocalChannel) {
    [...]
}
```

For Java, I don't see something similar in the [JDA GitHub documentation](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/8).

However, I can use `GuildVoiceJoinEvent` to detect each member who connects to a voice channel but it would consume more CPU resources for sure. Is there any other solution at the moment?

Comment: `I can use GuildVoiceJoinEvent to detect each member who connects to a voice channel but it would consume more CPU resources for sure` -- Does that matter?

Comment: @RobertHarvey If the server gets over 1k members someday, it should be. I can still use the current solution I posted for now waiting to find a new one later on.